# PPP connection to a virtualbox guest

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, serial-port, ppp

For testing some software, I'm trying to set up a PPP connection between an Ubuntu 18.04 host and an Ubuntu 16.04 guest running in VirtualBox.  So far I've tried:

- Creating virtual serial devices on the host with `socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyS14 PTY,link=/dev/ttyS15` and then connecting virtualbox's `COM1` to `/dev/ttyS14` as a host device - but VirtualBox complains that it can't set options on the port (in this case, `/dev/ttyS14` is a link to `/dev/pts/1`).
- Configuring VirtualBox's `COM1` as a host pipe to `/tmp/vbox-serial`.  But `pppd` doesn't know that the commandline option `/tmp/vbox-serial` is a serial port.
- Creating a virtual serial device and linking it to a socket with `socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyS14 PIPE:/tmp/vbox-serial` and configuring VirtualBox to connect its `COM1` port to and existing socket at `/tmp/vbox-serial` using the host pipe option, but this results in `VERR_NET_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on VM startup (`/tmp/vbox-serial` is `prw-rw-r-- 1 root tty` and VirtualBox is running as a user who is a member to the `tty` group).

Can anyone point  me to the right combination so that VirtualBox and pppd can communicate?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got something working over TCP.  On the host:

```
sudo socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyS14 TCP4-LISTEN:1236
sudo pppd /dev/ttyS14 4000000 192.168.1.1:192.168.1.2 asyncmap 0 proxyarp lock crtscts modem nodetach noauth
```

Configure the guest's `COM1` port as:
* Mode TCP
* Connect to existing pipe/socket
* Path/Address 127.0.0.1:1236

Then in the guest:

```
sudo pppd /dev/ttyS0 4000000 asyncmap 0 lock crtscts modem nodetach noauth
```

Assuming the link is established okay then setup NAT on the host:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i ppp0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And setup routing in the guest:

```
sudo ip route add default dev ppp0 metric 50
```

The VM should now be able to route traffic across the PPP link to the internet (assuming that your host has working internet access through `eth0`).